# ESET がインストールされた mac で、 ウェブアプリに [::1] のアドレスで接続できないのは何故?

Tags: macos, network, security, ipv6

セキュリティソフトの ESET を入れた mac にて開発を行っています。

この mac で、たとえば rails などの開発サーバーを立ち上げたとき、 `127.0.0.1:3000` などの ipv4 経由のアクセスでは rails に問題なく疎通できますが、 `localhost:3000` や `[::1]:3000` でアクセスしようとすると、ネットワークが eset のファイアウォールにてブロックされてしまいます。

ブロックされた通信のログを見ていると、以下のような通信が行われようとして、しかし既存のルールで許可されずブロックされているようだ、と思っています。

```
日時                 イベント                      ソース        ターゲット                 プロトコル      ユーザー
2020/05/18 14:12:03 使用できるルールが見つかりません    [::]:50129  [::1c1e:c3d1:0:0]:3000  TCP         root
```

これは、ブラウザで実行しようが、 curl で実行しようが、このような通信が発生し、ブロックされ、疎通ができないような事象が発生しています。

## 質問

この、 ipv6 としての通信で発生している、 `[::1c1e:c3d1:0:0]` へ向けての接続は一体何ですか?

- macOS が裏で何かやって、これが発生しているのでしょうか?
- それとも eset 自身が何かをやっているのでしょうか?
- そもそも、このターゲットのアドレスは一体、何者でしょうか?

## 追記

- Web Access 保護機能は、 off にしたけれども、挙動は変わりませんでした。( On でも Off でも、 localhost:3000 は接続されず、 127.0.0.1:3000 は接続される)

Comment: Eset も mac も使ってないので完全な当てずっぽうですが、名前解決や IPv6 周りが怪しいということですかね？

Comment: eset と、　macos 自身のIPv6 についての特殊な取り扱い、そのどちらかにより、見たこともない系統のアドレスへ向けての通信に、localhost への通信は変換されている、というのが私の認識です。名前解決がこのアドレスを利用している可能性は、、それは、この見たことないアドレスが、この私の　mac に割り当てられていることになり、それはそれで意味が分からないな、と感じています。

Comment: あー、補足として、外向き通信は全て許可(デフォルト設定により)なので、このブロックされてる通信は、内向きであるから、上記の推論を行なっている次第です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちら、最新のバージョン(@6.9.60.0) eset において、問題は解消された様子です。